# VBA Autofilter Set by Date in Excel - not showing any data

Tags: date, excel, autofilter, vba

The code below is a snippet of my full code for this project, but this is where its failing. The user types a date in cell C3 of which the autofilter will be set to. However when I do this the autofilter returns no data (even though it does exist). I've seen the query all over the forums and tried the numerous suggestions given from those questions but still can't get ant data to show. Can anyone provide some direction please. Date in excel is "dd/mm/yyyy"

```
Option Explicit

Sub autofilter_by_date()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet

Sheets("Log").Select

Dim dDate As Date
dDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")
dDate = DateSerial(Year(dDate), Month(dDate), Day(dDate))

With wks
    If Not .AutoFilterMode Then
Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Date Requested]]").AutoFilter
    End If
If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=dDate
Range("Table2[[#Headers],[H Name]]").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
End With

Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

**1.**

from

```
Dim dDate As Date
dDate = CDate(Format(Worksheets("Controls").Range("C3"), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

to

```
Dim dDate As String
dDate = Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3"), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

**2.**

from

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=dDate
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(dDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & CLng(dDate) + 1
```

Comment: Hi simoco, thanks for your help. I have tried this code and its not working for me. The autofilter is filtering but no data is being given. I have however hovered the mouse over this section of code and it is returning a date = '13/01/2014'.

Comment: I think its an issue with the autofilter and possibly its setup, but I don't fully understand this. I've tried pasting this date into the autofilter 'search section' and it doesn't return anything either. If selecting (not searching) through the autofilter manually I have to select year first, then month and then date. My colleague has mentioned european setup / international setup on dates. Again, any ideas relating to this?

Comment: can you provide some test workbook with your data? (i.e. using https://www.dropbox.com/)

Comment: I've joined Dropbox and put the file in a shared folder. Not sure how to get it to you though?

Comment: You should give me the link to your file

Comment: See my updated answer. And [here is wb with correct code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycdfbrqzr822rt7/JIMQ%20test%20file.xlsm). I've left some comments in the module.

Comment: That's brillant simoco. Thanks for the comments in the code also. My mistake on deleting that header name. Appreciate what you've done for me.

Answer (score 1):

Full code below, tried and tested. (Cell C4 in the excel sheet is a date shown as a number)

```
Option Explicit

Sub autofilter_by_date()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet

Sheets("Log").Select

Dim dDate As String
dDate = Format(Worksheets("Controls").Range("C4"))


With wks
    If Not .AutoFilterMode Then
Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Header Name]]").AutoFilter
    End If
If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(dDate), _
                 Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & CLng(dDate) + 1

Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Haulier Name]]").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
End With

Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

End Sub
```